# Bind Data to a tooltip on Mouseover from selected list item in Flex 4.5

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I have an image in flex that when I mouse over I want to be able to pull some data from a table based on what item is selected in the list.

Here is the image:

```
    <s:Image source="@Embed('assets/icons/question-mark_16.png')"toolTip=""/>
```

Here is the ArrayCollection:

```
    private var availableReports:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {listOrder: 1, label: "Activity Summary Report", data: "actySummary", url: ""},
            {listOrder: 2, label: "Activity Report", data: "actyReport", url: ""},
            {listOrder: 3, label: "Performance Metrics and Data", data: "pmadReport", 
                url: properties.getProperty("config.links.pmd")},
            {listOrder: 4, label: "More Detailed Reports...", data: "moreReports", 
                url: properties.getProperty("config.links.reports")}
        ]);
```

Here is the List Displaying the ArrayCollection:

```
    <s:List id="availableReportsList" width="100%"
    dataProvider="{availableReports}" selectedIndex="0"
    change="availableReportsList_changeHandler(event)"
    height="90">
    </s:List>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will pull data from the label.

```
    <s:Image source="@Embed('assets/icons/question-mark_16.png')" toolTip="{availableReportsList.selectedItem.label}"/>
```